# Android emulator access to IPv6 possible? Network is unreachable

Tags: android, eclipse, networking, emulation, ipv6

I am running an Android 4.0 emulator on windows 7 with a valid global ipv6 address. The emulator can access the ipv4 of the host machine addresses but not the ipv6 address. Pinging the ipv6 address from a third party site works.

Is there some magic trick to tell the emulator to use IPv6 as well? The emulator hasn't really got a lot of configuration options.

I always get the message "Network is unreachable".

Comment: File a bug against the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SDK 25.3.0 running Android Emulator in IPv6-only environment is finally supported. I tested with Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 running in Docker container with IPv6-only host. The main thing you need to know to do the trick is that it is only supported with **emulator** command and not supported e.g. for **emulator64-x86** command. So the following will work:

```
$ emulator -avd android6.0-1 -sdcard /200MB.img ...
```

... and the following will not:

```
$ emulator64-x86 -avd android6.0-1 -sdcard /200MB.img ...
```

Hope it helps somebody.