# Sending IPv6-packets from emulator to host-machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, ipv6

I'm trying to send IPv6 packets from my emulated android device to my host-machine. Is there any IPv6 address to reach the hosts ::1 address from the emulator (Something similar to 10.0.2.2 for IPv4)?
I didn't find any information about using IPv6 with an emulated device in the [emutlator networking guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) or searching the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ::1 is localhost, so you will never be able to reach that address from the emulator (which is an emulated host by itself and will have its own ::1 address)

Comment: The android emulator is using a virtual router to connect the host machine with the emulated device. When sending a packet to 10.0.2.2 from the emulated device, it will be redirected to the hosts 127.0.0.1 address by the virtual router. This is in case I'm using IPv4, but I have to test some IPv6 stuff so I need something similar for IPv6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the Android emulator has no support for IPv6. The latest word on it was from [three years ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/fg43cFyMPXE/I_-RGA-gt88J):

> I plan to add IPv6 support to the emulator, but it's really a non-trivial thing to do, given the state of the QEMU internal firewall/NAT. Hope it will be available soon enough, but I don't promise anything at the moment.

Best advice I can give you is to use a device. But note that there are a number of Android bugs relating to IPv6 over WiFi, so for the moment you'll want a carrier that has deployed IPv6 already.

Comment: Although that's not the answer I was hoping for, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This changed in SDK 25.3.0+. Posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609092/android-emulator-access-to-ipv6-possible-network-is-unreachable